# Xpath combining tags or nodes

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
<tr id="computer-report-tbl-row-0" ng-repeat="item in table.data.items" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <td id="column-name-0" class="table-cell-md" sc-ellipsis-title="" style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
        <a ui-sref="devices.computers-details({id:item.id})" route="devices.computers-details({id:item.id})" href="/manage/devices/computers/b97f242b-2ab6-6472-4926-6ca32301c2de">
            <ng-transclude><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">hello</span></ng-transclude>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td id="column-last-activity-from-now0" class="table-cell-date-age ng-binding">9 months ago</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get `<a>` tag ***if and only if*** the xpath contains `<td>` with `class = "table-cell-md"` AND `<td>` with `class='table-cell-date-age ng-binding'` and text `9 months ago`

so far I was thinking this:

```
//td[@class = 'table-cell-md']|/@*[@class='table-cell-date-age ng-binding' and text()='9 months ago']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below xpath to fulfill your condition:

```
//td[@class='table-cell-date-age ng-binding' and contains(.,'9 months ago')]/preceding-sibling::td[@class='table-cell-md']/a
```

**Explanation**:

- `//td[@class='table-cell-date-age ng-binding' and contains(.,'9 months ago')]` first locate the `<td>` tag which has class name `table-cell-date-age ng-binding`
  and text `9 months ago`
- `/preceding-sibling::` method is used to locate the `<td>` with class name `table-cell-md` because it is a immediate preceding sibling of your current located element
- `td[@class='table-cell-md']/a` locate the link present under desired `<td>`

Comment: Thank you very much. This also works and a new way to go about it. so I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//td[
    @class = 'table-cell-md'
    and following-sibling::td[
        @class='table-cell-date-age ng-binding' and text() = '9 months ago'
    ]
]/a
```

Use `following-sibling::td[1][...]` if you only want to consider the immediately following `<td>`.

Comment: Thank You very much. This really Helped I just started today with xpath so I was still learning and this helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Prabin Good to hear! (Consider ticking the answer as accepted when it helped answered the question.)

Comment: I was trying to accept it but because I am new, it is saying I don't have a reputation over 15. Unfortunately, but I believe/think if you vote my question then my reputation should be over 15 after.

Comment: @Prabin You can always accept answers (green checkmark). Vorting requires reputation (up 15, down 50, I think). The limits are there to prevent abuse, e.g. creating an army of sock-puppet accounts to vote for your own answers or downvote other people out of anger.

Comment: Oh got it. Thank you!! Did not know that. And makes sense thank you agian

Comment: @Prabin But apart from that you're right, I should have up-voted your question as well.